# How to resolve 'AttributeError' in 'yfinance' library while getting historical stock data for TSLA?

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, data-science

I'm trying to retrieve the historical stock data for TSLA using the yfinance library in Python and converting the index to a pandas DatetimeIndex in the UTC timezone. This is my code:

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd

# Get data for TSLA
tsla = yf.Ticker("TSLA")

# Get historical stock data for TSLA
stock_data = tsla.history(period="max")

# Remove any timezone information from the index
stock_data.index = stock_data.index.tz_localize(None)

# Convert the index to a pandas DatetimeIndex in UTC timezone
stock_data.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(stock_data.index, tz="UTC")
```

However, I'm getting an `AttributeError` while running the last line of this code
I've updated my pandas package to the latest version (2.1.0) and also tried various other solutions, such as using `stock_data.index = pd.to_datetime(stock_data.index, utc=True)` instead of `pd.DatetimeIndex`, but I'm still getting the same error.

Could this be a problem with the yfinance dataset or am I missing something in my code? Any help would be appreciated!

I've already tried updating my pandas version and ensuring that all other corrections have been made. However, I'm still experiencing this issue.

What could be causing this error, and how can I resolve it?

Comment: Hey, welcome to stackoverflow. I just ran this program on my end and had no issues. I have `Python 3.10.11`, `pandas 2.0.0` and `yfinance 0.2.18` installed.

Comment: I have python 3.10.11, pandas 2.0.1, and yfinance 0.1.67 so im guessing i have to update yfinance? im sorry im really new to this could you please tell me how to do that